# Normalizing LAScatalog only outputs one tile

Tags: r, lidr

I'm having trouble normalizing a LAScatalog. I wonder whether my methodology is flawed, or if something is possibly wrong with my dataset (a point cloud based on photogrammetry). When I try to normalize my LAScatalog, which contains 8 tiles, only one tile appears to output, even though the `summary()` function shows that both catalogs contain 8 tiles. My process is as follows:

---

First, `normalize_height()` runs smoothly.

`norm <- normalize_height(ctg, tin())`

[image]

However, `plot(norm)` only shows one tile.

[image]

Following are the summaries for `ctg` and `norm`, respectively.

[image]

[image]

I also tried a hybrid method with a DEM (as described in lidR handbook, [here](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/norm.html#hybrid-method)). But after creating a DEM, I still only see one tile.

`dem <- rasterize_terrain(ctg, algorithm =tin())`

`plot(dem)`

[image]

Next, I attempt the hybrid approach with the DEM I created.

`norm2 <- normalize_height(ctg, dtm=dem, tin())`

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts or suspicions as to why I'm only seeing one tile in my output? Or why my normalization is failing, more generally?

Comment: I see that `norm` contains 8 files, but the extent is incorrect. Hard to says anything without a reproducible example. Reproduce and produce more useful data to maybe [report a bug](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/issues). I can't say anything with screeshoot of code and no reproduce example. Your normalization with a DTM fails because the DTM does not encompasses the lidar data. This one is expected.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Do you have a recommendation for how I would create a reproducible example for this? Would it involve uploading some zipped data?

Comment: Maybe 2 or 4 files are enough to reproduce.

Comment: Got it; just posted a Github issue 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRR answered my question over in Github issues, [here](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/issues/729)  I simply needed to add a template to my file path for `opt_output_files()`. Without a template path, my previous tile kept being overwritten by the next one, leaving just the last tile. I needed to add something like this:

```
R_OUTPUT_FILES <- "{ORIGINALFILENAME}_chm"
opt_output_files(ctg) <- R_OUTPUT_FILES
```